# loop tool does not create a circle

Tags: modeling, add-on, edges

I want to make a circle edges loop using loop tool ads on. This is my edges
[image]

[image]

And when I apply the loop tool circle this is what happened
[image]

[here's my blend file](https://pasteall.org/blend/e6c2633f4c7843dcaff96bc6a9fe30a8)

Comment: @JachymMichal unfortunately the To Sphere function does not work for me

Comment: You might have some bad geometry.  Can you share your blend file?

Comment: @MartyFouts yes. check it out. This is my first time using paste all. I can't use blender exchange because it keeps loading

Comment: You have a bunch of duplicate vertices that are messing up the *Circle* tool.

Comment: @HISEROD how to check it out and then delete the duplicate?

Comment: I wrote a detailed explanation as an answer. Please vote it up if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have bad geometry.  To find and fix it it, I did the following in edit mode:

Go to face select mode and select most of the faces.

[image: Most faces selected]

Then type h to hide those faces

[image: most faces hidden]

This isn't strictly necessary but it makes it easier to follow the next bit.

Next I went into vertex select mode, and selected every vertex

[image: every vertex selected]

and I typed m to bring up the merge menu

[image: merge menu]

and I selected "by distance"

[image: selecting by distance]

and in the lower bar it told me that it had removed vertices:

[image: removed 43 vertices]

Next I tried to select the vertices that you want to make a circle using alt-LMB after deselecting all with ALT-A.  But that failed because you have some extra vertices that are not near enough to each other for 'by distance' to work with the default settings so I opened the merge tool information (at the bottom left of the 3d view)

[image: merge by distance setting]

I had to set the merge distance to 0.01 to get six additional vertices.

After that I reselected the ring, and Loop tool -> circle worked fine.

[image: circle made]

follow that with ALT-h to unhide the hidden faces and that's that.

Comment: wow thank you so much

Comment: Please stop trying to edit this answer.  Most of the edit attempts have done things like introduced capital letters, which change the behavior of blender compared to the lower case letters.  Also, this is not a step by step how to, and I wrote it the way I did because it really is 'what I did' and not 'how you should'.